nginx dependencies in deb
I have create my own x.deb. This x.deb needs to install the nginx. The problem is the machine that i need to install the deb don't have network access. Its possible to change my one x.deb to install the nginx?

You can get .deb installers of nginx from packages.ubuntu.com, e.g. from here https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/amd64/nginx/download

i change the approach. i create another package that has dependencies of nginx and my x.deb. but to install the dependencies i have to use the aptitude.
